# Unable to ssh into virtual machine on host only network

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have created a virtual machine in virtual box with host only network. I am able to ping to the virtual machine but when i try to ssh into the same machine it reject my request with following error

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.56 port 22: No route to host
```

I am able to ssh within the virtual machine.

ifconfig result on host machine :

```
vboxnet0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00
         inet addr:192.168.56.1 Bcast:192.168.56.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
         inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
         RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
         TX bytes:17432 (17.4 KB)
```

and ifconfig within virtual machine just shows the loopback information .

Comment: Don't remove newlines and spaces when you copy-paste the output of a command, it makes it unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the `vboxnet0` device has address `192.168.56.1`. This also shows in your config. Your `ssh` statement point to another address where '56' and '1' are exchanged. Your `ping` command probably just pings the hosts vboxnet0 device and since you only have a loopback device in your guest machine I suppose that you did not configure networking within the guest.

You might try to use `ifconfig eth0 192.168.56.101/32 up` (assuming that eth0 is your guests network interface name) within the guest operating system and try to ping `ping 192.168.56.1` from the guest or `ping 192.168.56.101` from the host. If that works, try to ssh using `ssh 192.168.56.101` from the host.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1233489/457084 for more details on this type of solution